# It is possible to develop application on mac with docker without running container as root?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-mac

I'm setting up docker-compose for my php project on my mac. I mount a shared volume with all the code from host machine into container.
Obviously, I do not want to run the php container as `root` user. But **do I have another option?**

I tried:

- Changing owner of the project files in Dockerfile
- Changing owner in entrypoint

Both methods work fine, until you create a file in IDE - in this case the file appears to be owner by `root` inside container and then you need to restart the container (which is horrible experience for development)

- Changing UID for user `www-data` in container to UID from my host user.

It didn't work, since the files are owned by `root`

---

Do I miss any points here?

Comment: It somehow works OK on Vagrant with NFS. I have Vagrant running on my MAC, and run docker inside that Vagrant. But I guess  it is due to NFS implementation

Comment: did you check `docker run --user` ?   `-u, --user string                    Username or UID (format: <name|uid>[:<group|gid>])`

Comment: I did, it doesn't make any difference, when I create new file in IDE the file is owner by root inside the container

Comment: I'm just wondering if everyone just runs development containers as root?

Comment: I prefer using Docker toolbox instead of the native version as final deployments are always on linux machines

Comment: don't you have the problem with toolbox I have? Docker toolbox seems to be a legacy project

Comment: What kind of issues do you face?

Comment: I am not able to run my container as www-data user. I do not want nor I am going to run it as root

Comment: Have you look at this? https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

Comment: I have, this maps users on hosts machine. Even though I am not root on host machine, new files inside container appear to be owned by root